# How to convert this type of Date Format in Android

Tags: android, date

I am receiving this type of Date `Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 +0000` as a `String`.

I had tried to convert it as `Wed, 14 Nov 2012` using different ways like that of using `SimpleDateFormat` type of changing the format of the Date but got Parsing Errors.

How would I convert this type of `Date` so that after converting,I would get
only `Wed, 14 Nov 2012` type of `Date`.

Thanks.

Code that I have tried:

```
String stringDate="Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 +0000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS");
Date parseDate = sdf.parse(stringDate);
String conDateinString = sdf.format(date1);
String lastDate=DateFormat.format("EEE, dd MMM yyyy", new Date(Long.parseLong(conDateinString))).toString();
```

stringDate--My first date that is to be parsed.
  conDateinString -- converted date in String Format.
  lastDate -- final date that I tried to Obtain.

Comment: What you have try ? Code Plese ?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Can't you decode the first letters to see what day it is etc. ... one by one if the default methods do not work?

Comment: u can use substring to separate it know?

Comment: Actually,I didnot need the time anymore so i tried to convert the first date in to Simple date,and then tried to again convert that simple date to the required date format. Sorry Guys if I am Wrong :)

Comment: have a look this url . you will get nice tutorial about all type of date object conversions http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html and also have a look at this .http://www.roseindia.net/java/javadate/date-format.shtml

Comment: have a look at this too http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/date-and-time-format.html

Comment: Thnks all for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this format of `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String t = "Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 +0000";

// To parse input string
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000", Locale.US);

// To format output string
SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US);

System.out.println(to.format(from.parse(t)));
```

The output of this code would be:

```
Wed, 14 Nov 2012
```

Comment: Getting this Exception
  
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Mon, 11 Mar 2013 12:09:58 +0000

Comment: Because format of `Mon, 11 Mar 2013 12:09:58 +0000` is different that format of `Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 0000` - there is no `+` in the latter. So, if you want to parse it with a `+`, just change `SimpleDateFormat from` to `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000`.

Comment: Yes..you are right..changing gives me the Right Answer.Please update your answer so that I would accept it as final answer...and many thanks to you and all.

Comment: @HareshChaudhary - I've updated it. And also I've updated your question to include the `+` sign.